# Use OpenXML to indent a specific column in a table

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm looking to use OpenXML to indent a specific column in a table (in the case I'm working on it's always the second column in from the left in the table) and I was wondering about the specifics of utilising the Indentation class in OpenXML.

I have column and row ids in my program so I can identify the column easily enough but implementing the indentation is proving a bit more tricky.

Any help or pointers from someone with experience using it would be very much appreciated - new to using OpenXML so I may be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you a really crude hack. It's the equivalent of recording macros to see what the VBA looks like. (I heard about that from people who program VBA. I've never done that, ever.)

Download [OpenXMLSDKToolV25.msi](http://I%20can%20tell%20you%20a%20really%20bad%20hack.%20Download%20the%20[OpenXml%20SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)). The full name of the app is "Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office." It's a productivity tool for a productivity tool!

Create a short Word document that has the feature you want. Save it and open it in the Productivity Tool. Press the "Reflect Code" button and it will generate C# code to create the document in OpenXML. Then you dig through the code to find the part that does what you want.

(snipping some parts)

```
Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(){ RsidParagraphMarkRevision = "00000000", RsidParagraphAddition = "00000000", RsidParagraphDeletion = "00000000", RsidParagraphProperties = "00000000", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00000000" };    
Indentation indentation1 = new Indentation(){ Left = "720", Right = "0", FirstLine = "0" };
paragraphProperties1.Append(indentation1);
```

...somewhere after creating the table and cells...

```
tableCell1.Append(paragraph1);
```

Comment: I don't think I'd call this a crude hack. I think this is one of the best ways to learn how to use the OpenXML SDK. Specifically, the process of saving a before and after version of an office document for a change you want to do programmatically and then using the built in Compare Files functionality of the Productivity Tool to show you only the XML data that changed has helped me get to solutions much quicker than just looking at the API or using Intellisense.

Comment: Thanks. I try to be extra modest if I suspect that there's a better way and everyone knows it except for me. But in this case the documentation hasn't been too helpful. (I also don't work with it very much.)